# If $null(A)=\{0\}$, how does it relate to eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

if $A$ is $n \times n$ and $null(A)=\{0\}$, does it have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors?

Comment: No. It just says that zero is *not* one of the matrix's eigenvalues.

Comment: Detail: $\mbox{null} A$, as far as I know, usually denotes the nullity of $A$, that is the dimension of the nullspace of $A$. So it's rather $\mbox{null} A=0 \;\iff\;\mbox{ker} A=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

No, e.g. $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in this case $A\begin{pmatrix}a \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ for all $a$, so the nullspace is not $\{0\}$.

Comment: @Stahl Thx, corrected. If I'm not mistaken it was not far from a counterexample.

Comment: @BobR The statement of your problem as above doesn't ask for $n$ distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: @BobR If you add that the matrix has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors since eigenvectors to different eigenvalues are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Nul $A$ is the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue zero (if this space is nonzero).  So Null $A = \{0\}$ implies that zero is not an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$.  It doesn't give much more information about eigenvectors and eigenvalues than that.